# django-autocomplete-light filter queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-autocomplete-light

I am trying to use django-autocomplete-light but I have some problems.
I would like to filter the queryset in the `ModelChoiceField`.
If I don't use auto-complete my result selection is correct but if I use widget it doesn't work correctly, it shows all records.

Here is my code:

```
class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(MyModelAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.fields['my_field'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            MyModel.objects.filter(status=1),
            widget=autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget('MyModelAutocomplete')
    )

class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelAdminForm
```

Answer (score 3):

You should set `MyModelAutocomplete.choices`, either via `register()`:

```
autocomplete_light.register(MyModel, choices=MyModel.objects.filter(status=1))
```

Or within the class:

```
class MyModelAutocomplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase):
    choices = MyModel.objects.filter(status=1)
```

Refer to docs for more:

- [AutocompleteModel API docs](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-autocomplete_light.autocomplete.model)
- [Using `register()` to pass class attributes](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#autocomplete_light.registry.AutocompleteRegistry.register): "In addition, keyword arguments will be set as class attributes."
- [Overriding `choices_for_request()`](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/autocomplete.html#security) might be useful if you need to filter choices based on the user.

I would like to automate this, but the widget isn't aware about the form field instance unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the filter inside `MyModelAutocomplete` by defining a method

```
class MyModelAutocomplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase):
     choices=MyModel.objects.all()
     def choices_for_request(self):
        choices = choices.filter(status=1)
        return self.order_choices(choices)[0:self.limit_choices]
```

`choices_for_request` is mostly used for dynamic filterming

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to figure out how to do this within the autocomplete-light documentation.  I figured out how, but not without a bit of digging, so hopefully this is helpful.

In the autocomplete_light_registry.py file, fill out the "name" and "choices" parameters:

```
#myapp/autocomplete_light_registry.py
autocomplete_light.register(MyModel,
    #... Other Parameters ...
    name = 'SpecialMyModelAutocomplete',
    choices = YourQuerySetHere, #e.g. MyModel.objects.filter(...)
)
```

The default name is "MyModelAutocomplete" so if you include more than one registered autocomplete for a model, you need to specify which one you want to use (otherwise it uses the first one in the registry, NOT the default).

To specify, use "autocomplete_names" which is (from the docs) "A dict of field_name: AutocompleteName to override the default autocomplete that would be used for a field."  In my case I'm using it within the django admin.

```
#myapp/admin.py
class MyModelAdminForm(autocompletelight.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        autocomplete_names = {'field_name':'SpecialMyModelAutocomplete'}
```

Note that you don't need to include any fields for which you want to use the default Autocomplete in autocomplete_names.  Incidentally "autocomplete_exclude" and "autocomplete_fields" may also be of interest here and are analogous to "fields" and "exclude" in a ModelAdmin to specify which fields to include/exclude from using autocomplete.

Addition:
You can also use "autocomplete_names" in the modelform_factory:

```
form = autocomplete_light.modelform_factory(MyOtherModel,autocomplete_names={MyFieldName:'MyModelAutocomplete'}) #where MyFieldName is a ForeignKey to MyModel
```

From the docs:

```
autocomplete_light.forms.modelform_factory(model,autocomplete_fields=None,autocomplete_exclude=None,autocomplete_names=None,registry=None,**kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you for this contribution, it really pushed me to the right direction. I have used the following parts of the documentation: [High Level Basics](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/docs_rewrite/cookbook.html#high-level-basics), [autocomplete_names](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=modelform_factory#autocomplete_light.forms.ModelForm.autocomplete_names) and [model_form_factory](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=modelform_factory#autocomplete_light.forms.modelform_factory)